# How to change the text of a button in a drop down menu with the text of the selected li list item - jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to change the text of a dropdown-menu with the text of the selected item.

```
//HTML
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">DATE</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">TODAY</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

//JQUERY
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(e){
    //e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.btn-default').html($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean like this? **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/968gkprd/)**

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(e){
    //e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('ul').siblings('.btn-default').html($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`closest()` only searches ancestors up the tree, and.btn-default is not an ancestor of your `<li>`.  Also, are you sure you want `.html()` and not `.text()`?

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function (e) {
    //e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.btn-group').children('.btn-default').text($(this).text());
});
```